# Using native camera with AMP

Tags: amp-html

Hi I want to build an AMP (Accelerated Mobile Page) site, but I want to integrate native camera support. I want to understand if this could be accomplished with AMP? If not, what could be a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per [issue #18919](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/18919), the recommended approach is to build a non-AMP HTML page that handles whatever camera functionality you want and then use [amp-iframe](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-iframe) to embed this into your AMP page.

Comment: Hi @fstanis, Thanks for replaying back. I will have a look of that approach. Cheers.